# Python Gurobi Constraint is not being enforced

Tags: python, gurobi

I am trying to build an air traffic model between 3 airports. I have constraints which ensure that regardless of the airport of arrival or departure number of flights an airport handle is maximum 5. However, somehow the constraints for that between lines 160-179 dont seem to work.

When the model is solved I check the number of flights per hour and see more than 5 flights taking off for multiple hours

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Oct 14 13:00:53 2023

@author: berks
"""

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Jun 15 12:55:23 2023

@author: berks
"""

# 1. Open the text file for writing
output_file = open(r"C:\\Users\\berks\\Desktop\\Code Outputs\\095", "w")

# 2. Redirect console outputs to the file
import sys
original_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = output_file



from LtdExcel_handling_code import process_excel_filefor_af
from LtdExcel_handling_code import process_excel_filefor_depf
from LtdExcel_handling_code import calculate_tf_from_excel
from LtdExcel_handling_code import process_for_flight_times
from LtdExcel_handling_code import calculate_tf_deviation
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB
import random
from newScenGen import scen_gen


file_path = r"C:\Users\berks\Desktop\I0000_demand.xlsx" 





# Create a new Gurobi model
model = gp.Model("MSATFM")

# Sets
F = range(1,401)  # Set of flights
A = ['JFK', 'LAX', 'ORD']  # Set of airports (using integer indices)
T = range(1, 97)  # Set of time periods
Omega = range(0,10)  # Set of scenarios
P = range(0,1)

# Parameters

alpha = 0.85
ef = {}  # Cost associated with flight f at time t

# Generate 3942 flights with 96 time parameters
for flight in F:
    for time in T:
        ef[(flight, time)] = random.randint(5, 9)
        

tf = process_for_flight_times(file_path)  # Duration of flight time for flight f
Atk = {}  # Nominal capacity of arrival airport k at time t
Dtk = {}  # Nominal capacity of departure airport k at time t

# Generate 96 time parameters for each airport
for airport in ['JFK', 'LAX', 'ORD']:
    for time in T:
        Atk[(airport, time)] = random.randint(4,8) if airport == 'JFK' else random.randint(4,8) if airport == 'LAX' else random.randint(4,8)



# Generate 96 time parameters for each airport
for airport in ['JFK', 'LAX', 'ORD']:
    for time in T:
        Dtk[(airport, time)] = random.randint(4,8) if airport == 'JFK' else random.randint(4,8) if airport == 'LAX' else random.randint(4,8)



A_D = scen_gen(10)     

AtkOmega = {}  # Nominal capacity of arrival airport k at time t under scenario omega
DtkOmega = {}  # Nominal capacity of departure airport k at time t under scenario omega

for omega in Omega:
    for airport in ['JFK','LAX','ORD']:
        for time in T:
            DtkOmega[(airport,time,omega)] = A_D[omega][0] if airport == 'JFK' else A_D[omega][1] if airport == 'LAX' else A_D[omega][2] 
        

for omega in Omega:
    for airport in ['JFK','LAX','ORD']:
        for time in T:
            AtkOmega[(airport,time,omega)] = A_D[omega][0] if airport == 'JFK' else A_D[omega][1] if airport == 'LAX' else A_D[omega][2] 

#AtkOmega = {(k, t, omega): random.randint(8, 18) for k in A for t in T for omega in Omega}  # Capacity of arrival airport k at time t under scenario omega
#DtkOmega = {(k, t, omega): random.randint(8, 18) for k in A for t in T for omega in Omega}  # Capacity of departure airport k at time t under scenario omega



pOmega = 1/10




#pOmega = {'JFK':[86.02739726027397,11.506849315068493,2.4657534246575343] ,'ORD':[81.36986301369863,13.698630136986301,4.931506849315069] ,'LAX':[93.97260273972603,4.657534246575342,1.36986301369863]}  # Probability of scenario omega
af = process_excel_filefor_af(file_path)  # Arrival airport of flight f
df = process_excel_filefor_depf(file_path)  # Departure airport of flight f
tauf = {1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 3, 4: 1, 5: 2,6:1,7:2,8:3,9:1}  # Planned arrival time of flight f
Tf = calculate_tf_from_excel(file_path, 12)  #available flight slots for flight f, 1-96


ta = calculate_tf_deviation(file_path, 12)






# Decision Variables
xf = model.addVars(F, T, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x")  # Binary variable x_f(t)
yfOmega = model.addVars(F, T, Omega, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="y")  # Binary variable y_fω(t)
z = model.addVars(Omega,F, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, lb=-1,name='z') #Variable z_fw(t)
n = model.addVars(Omega, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb=0,name='n') #Variable n_w
eta = model.addVars(P,lb=0 ,vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS,name ='eta') #CVaR variable eta



# Objective Function
obj = (gp.quicksum(ef[f, t] * xf[f, t] for f in F for t in T) + eta[0] +
       (1/(1-alpha))*gp.quicksum(pOmega *n[omega] for omega in Omega for t in T))
model.setObjective(obj, GRB.MINIMIZE)



# Constraints

for f in F:
    model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(xf[f, t] for t in T ) == 1)   #4.4.2

for omega in Omega:
    for f in F:
        model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(yfOmega[f, t, omega] for t in T) == 1)  #4.4.3

for omega in Omega:
    model.addConstr(n[omega] >= 0)                #4.4.14
    

for omega in Omega:
    model.addConstr(n[omega] >= gp.quicksum(z[omega,f] for f in F) - eta[0])           #4.4.11
            
    
for omega in Omega:
    for f in F:
        model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(t * (xf[f,t] - yfOmega[f,t,omega])  for t in T) <= z[omega,f])        #4.4.9
        model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(t * (yfOmega[f,t,omega] - xf[f,t])  for t in T) <= z[omega,f])        #4.4.10


for t in T:
    for k in A:
            model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(xf[f, t + tf[f]]  for f in F  if (t + tf[f] <= 96) and af[f] == k) <= 3)     #Atk[k, t]
                 


for t in T:
    for k in A:
        model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(xf[f, t]  for f in F if df[f] == k) <= 3)        #Dtk[k, t]
                
for omega in Omega:
    for t in T:
        for k in A:
            model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(yfOmega[f, t + tf[f], omega] for f in F if t + tf[f] <= 96 and af[f] == k) <= 3)       #AtkOmega[k, t, omega]
         

for omega in Omega:
    for t in T:
        for k in A:
             model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(yfOmega[f, t , omega] for f in F if  df[f] == k) <= 3)                       #DtkOmega[k, t, omega]
                 

#model.addConstrs((yfOmega[f, t, omega] <= gp.quicksum(xf[f, tau] for tau in T if tau <= t)
#                 for f in F for t in T for omega in Omega))

# Optimize the model
model.optimize()


#for i in xf:
#    if i !=1:
#        print("xf"+str(i)+"=1")
#    else:    
#        print("xf"+str(i)+"=0")
#       
#for i in yfOmega:
#    if i !=1:
#        print("yfOmega"+str(i)+"=1"+str(type(i)))
#    else:    
#        print("yfOmega"+str(i)+"=0"+str(type(i)))        
       
        
if model.status == GRB.OPTIMAL:
    print("Optimal solution found!")
    for f in F:
       for t in T:
            if xf[f, t].x == 1:
                print(f, t,"Flight is scheduled at time")
           # else:
             #   print("Flight", f, "isnt scheduled at time", t)
                
    for omega in Omega:
        for f in F:
           for t in T:
               if yfOmega[f, t,omega].x == 1:
                        print(f, t, omega,"Flight is scheduled at time under scenario")
                    #else:
                      #  print("Flight", f, "isnt scheduled at time", t, "under scenario", omega)
                      
                      

                      
                    
else:
    print("No solution found.")
    
    
    
    
    
    # Create a counter dictionary for each scenario
checkcount = 0 
checkcount0 = 0
checkcountOM = {omega: 0 for omega in Omega}
checkcount0OM = {omega: 0 for omega in Omega}

checkcountPL = 0
checkcount0PL = 0

checkcountMIN = 0
checkcount0MIN = 0
# ...

# Constraints
# ...

# Count the number of matches between xf and yfOmega for each scenario

for f in F:
    #for t in T:
        if xf[f, ta[f]].x  == 1:
            checkcount += 1
        else:
            checkcount0 += 1

print('===================================')     


for f in F:
    if xf[f, ta[f]-1].x == 1:
        checkcountMIN += 1
    else:
        checkcount0MIN += 1
    




for f in F:
    if xf[(f, ta[f]+1)].x == 1:
        checkcountPL += 1
    else:
        checkcount0PL += 1




            
for omega in Omega:
    for f in F:
        #for t in T:
            if yfOmega[f, ta[f],omega].x  == 1:
                checkcountOM[omega] += 1
            else:
                checkcount0OM[omega] += 1
                            
            

# Print the results for each scenario
print(checkcount)   
print(checkcount0)   


print('===================================PLPLPLPL')     

print(checkcountPL)   
print(checkcount0PL)       

    
print('===================================MINMINMIN')                 

 
print(checkcountMIN)   
print(checkcount0MIN)      


sys.stdout = original_stdout
output_file.close()

print("Console outputs have been written to the file.")
```

The constraints that aren't enforced are as given below:

```
for t in T:
        for k in A:
                model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(xf[f, t + tf[f]]  for f in F  if (t + tf[f] <= 96) and af[f] == k) <= 3)     #Atk[k, t]
                     
    
    
    for t in T:
        for k in A:
            model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(xf[f, t]  for f in F if df[f] == k) <= 3)        #Dtk[k, t]
                    
    for omega in Omega:
        for t in T:
            for k in A:
                model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(yfOmega[f, t + tf[f], omega] for f in F if t + tf[f] <= 96 and af[f] == k) <= 3)       #AtkOmega[k, t, omega]
             
    
    for omega in Omega:
        for t in T:
            for k in A:
                 model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(yfOmega[f, t , omega] for f in F if  df[f] == k) <= 3)                       #DtkOmega[k, t, omega]
```

Comment: Sorry! Newbie mistake. I thought it would show line numbers. I added the mentioned constraints to the bottom of the problem definition.

Answer (score 1):

Can't assure this is the problem as your code is not reproduceble, but comprehensions like

`(yfOmega[f, t + tf[f], omega] for f in F if t + tf[f] <= 96 and af[f] == k)`

can generate unexpected results as the conditions can be not well interpreted depending on object types. I would try to encapsulate each condition with parentesis:

`(yfOmega[f, t + tf[f], omega] for f in F if ((t + tf[f] <= 96) and (af[f] == k)))`

Also it seems to be an indentation problem in the first constraint but i assume it is stack overflow formatting.